# Series + Number theory problem from JEE exam .

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series

[image: This is my question , answers are given. I tried different ways but couldn't solve it.]

My approach : Used variables for given conditions and made some equations. I got the AP as 3,5,7 and GP as 1,3,27 but it is not matching with the condition given in the question.  I would really appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Comment: JEE - Joint entrance EXAM

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax rather than posting image. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$a_2=\frac{a_1+a_3}{2}=\frac{15-a_2}{2}\implies a_2=5, a_1+a_3=10$$
but $a_1,a_3$ are not supposed to be integers.
Similarly,
$$b_2^2=b_1b_3=\frac{27}{b_2}\implies b_2=3, b_1b_3=9$$
but $b_1,b_3$ are not supposed to be integers.
Moreover
$$(a_1+b_1)(a_3+b_3)=(a_2+b_2)^2=(5+3)^2=64=2^6$$
Therefore $a_1+b_1=2^{6-n}\leq a_3+b_3=2^n$ with $n=3,4,5,6$.
By checking the four cases, it turns out that the good one is $n=6$ and that the maximum value is
$$a_3=\frac{73+7\sqrt{73-4\cdot 3}}{2}\approx 63.836.$$
Hence the given answers are both confirmed.

Comment: @SAMBHAVMISHRA Given $n$, solve the equations and find $a_1,a_3,b_1,b3$. The largest value of $n$ gives the largest $a_3$. I am sure you will be able to fill the details.

Comment: @SAMBHAVMISHRA We know that $a_1+a_3=10$, $b_1b_3=9$, $a_1+b_1=1$, $a_3+b_3=2^6$. Now find $a_3$.